# custom authorization filter for web api getting called multiple times

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, authorization, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a custom authorization filter for my Web API controller methods. My custom filter looks like this :-

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string _action;

    public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute()
    {
    }

    public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
      //authorization logic
    }
}
```

I have registered the filter in web Api config.

The problem is the filter is getting called multiple number of times. I want it to be called only for the method decorated with [ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute("ActionName")].

Any direction will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to control how many times it is called. However, there is an easy workaround:

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_action) {
       // do your logic here
   }
   else {
       return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
   }
}
```